# Android push notification expand on click

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

My target is to show notification in normal mode.

[image]

After click on it to be expanded like example.

[image]

From here I must be able to click on buttons. Problem is that when I add

```
 .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
     .setBigContentTitle(someBigTitle)
     .bigText(someString)))
```

it ovelaps the exsisting small test

```
.setContentText(someSmallText)
.setSubText(someSmallSubText)
```

and after click did not expand. I do not want to navigate to another activity on click. What must be my intent? Full code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
android.app.Notification mNotification = buildAndroidNotification(notification.getTitle(), someLogo, notification.getSubject(), pIntent, true);
mNotification.flags |= android.app.Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(2, mNotification);
```

and builder:

```
mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(smallHeading)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .setContentIntent(intent)
    .setContentText(someSmallText)
    .setSubText(someSmallSubText)
    .addAction(R.drawable.some_icon, some_str, null)
    .addAction(R.drawable.some_icon, some_str2, null)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .setBigContentTitle(someBigTitle)
        .bigText(someString))
    .setWhen(created)
    .build();
```

Comment: there is no way to expand notification on click. It only can be expanded by user manually.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Please add this comment as an answer.

Comment: @JafarKhQ only if has example how is that possible

Comment: Workaround came to my head. You could try make after clicking small notification to put new notification with big picture. Just use same notification ID

Comment: @VygintasB in this case if you have multiple notifications (from different apps) the new notification will not have the same position as the old one- not a good UX!

Comment: @JafarKhQ if using same notification ID should replace existing one. Correct me if i'm wrong